# Query all subscribers to find the subscriber key related to the contacts from mobile Data View

Tags: dataextensions, data-views, sfmc-business-unit, system

I would like to retrieve users who received sms and retrieve their salesforce ContactID. I had created a Data Extension from the template of the SMSMessageTracking DataView in a child Business Unit. On this DE, I find the subscriberId field and I would like to declare that this field is linked (equal) to the SystemData ContactID (in the attached file) in order to retrieve the ContactKey (which is equal to the Salesforce ContactID).

I don't know in which table SystemData ContactID is stored to query it from a child B.U. I was thinking that I could find it in All Subscribers but I wrote I can't query it from a B.U level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the same as the SubscriberID, so you would just query the SubscriberID in the same SMSTracking Data view.